# HTML audio is muted On iOS or iOS emulator

Tags: jquery, ios, html, audio

Firstly, I am sorry because I have no iOS device but I use [appetize](https://appetize.io). I have used simple HTML audio on a site but when I am checking from this emulator it does not make any sound. My friend also checked from his iOS (real device) and said no sound is being played. As a code example, you can see [THIS example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all) which also play but does not make any sound on "appetize" emulator and it seems muted automatically. I just used this simple code and no autoplay option is used.

Please put your valuable suggestion and enlighten me.
Thanks

Comment: Check this youtube video maybe it can help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Doanzn6alA&t=4s

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, But I got the solution. The [appetize.io](https://appetize.io/) online emulator has no sound support feature and I found a very nice alternative emulator https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com